# Defining conditions in protocols

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have a protocol like this:

```
@protocol ProfileSubObjects <NSObject, NSCoding>
@required
- (BOOL) hasGraph;

@optional
- (NSArray *) xGraphValues;
- (NSArray *) yGraphValues;
```

I want to make required this two optional methods if hasGraph is equal to YES.
Is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Methods are either required by a protocol or they're not. For one thing, the value of -hasGraph isn't known at compile time. Since it's an instance method rather than a class method, it's not even known at run time until you create a particular object. Furthermore, the object might report different values for -hasGraph at different times.

The best thing to do here is to simply document the fact that if -hasGraph returns YES, the -xGraphValues and -yGraphValues are expected to be implemented. You could enforce that by throwing an exception, or you could fail gracefully and just not draw any data if those methods aren't implemented. Use the -respondsToSelector: method to check whether the method is implemented before you call it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. At least, not like this. However there is a deeper issue. The question suggests consideration of compile versus runtime checking and object orientation.

Marking something as @optional or @required means that you wish to perform compile time checking that those objects fulfil the protocol contract of providing implementations - or not in the case of @optional - of those methods.

Therefore there is no reason to have that compile time checking dependent upon the value of a runtime variable, in this case hasGraph.

A better approach would be to make use of the respondsToSelector message check. Alternatively you could have a subclass that has a graph and supplies x and y graph values.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible; the result of hasGraph will be known only at runtime, whereas the required/optional parts of a protocol are used for the compiler to check things out at compile time.

What you probably want to do is to add a strong note to the effect that if hasGraph returns YES then xGraphValues and yGraphValues must be implemented, bringing a little informality to your formal protocol. You can always do something like:

```
if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(xGraphValues)] && 
   [object respondsToSelector:@selector(yGraphValues)])
```

To verify at runtime whether an object implements the parts of the protocol you need in order to be able to do a particular operation on it. It'd probably be smart to put that stuff in an NSAssert if you want someone who implements a non-conformant object to be able to find out what they did wrong through a debug build.